# How to programmatically add data to a hierarchical Infragistics UltraWinGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am able to add a record to the top band using

```
grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].AddNew();
```

But when I create this record, I need to also add some child records at band 1. How do I do that? I am getting an error:

> *Unable to add a row:Row insertion not suported by this datasource.*

This is my code:

```
 grid.DataSource = this.ultraDataSource2;
 this.ultraDataSource2.Band.AllowAdd = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
```

What setting has to be changed to allow addition of child records also when a parent record is added?

Comment: Have you tried to switch the order of the two lines above? (I mean, first AllowAdd=True then binding)

Comment: Tried that too. Still same..Are there other ways to add new row to parent band and child bands both..

Comment: The order the properties are set shouldn't be relevant.  Allowing adding is also the default so you shouldn't need to set it.  I provided code that shows how to set AllowAdd to true for a child band in an answer.  If this doesn't work, then it will help if you can provide more code for how you have set up your UltraDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the first child band to allow adding with the following:

```
this.ultraDataSource1.Band.ChildBands[0].AllowAdd = DefaultableBoolean.True;
```